# @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT) on method of repository of entity with inheritance and versionning leads to SQLGrammarException

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I know, the title is a bit confusing but I have a simple example showing you exactly the issue.

**TLDR;** With @Lock annotation on a find method of my repository, once I'm saving my entity after updating it, I got a SQLGrammarException because Hibernate(?) is using the parent class name as the table name instead of the child class...

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
> not execute statement [ERROR: relation "animal" does not exist
> Position : 8] [update animal set version=? where id=? and version=?];
> SQL [update animal set version=? where id=? and version=?]

**I don't have any issue if I remove the @Lock annotation.**

**Context:** migration from spring-boot 2.7.x to 3.2.3 (and then to hibernate 6). No issue with spring-boot 2.7.x

1. Let's create this abstract class with **@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Animal {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="animal_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="animal_sequence", sequenceName="animal_sequence", allocationSize=100)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Please note the @Version annotation.**

2. Then here is one entity extending this one, Dog.

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Dog extends Animal {

    public Dog() {
        super("dog");
    }

}
```

3. Here is the repository, please note the usage of @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)

```
@Repository
public interface AnimalRepository extends JpaRepository<Animal, Long> {

    @Override
    @Lock(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)
    List<Animal> findAll(); // Let's pretend there are some filters
}
```

4. And now my service

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AnimalService {

    private final AnimalRepository animalRepository;

    public <T extends Animal> T saveAndFlush(final T animal) {
        return animalRepository.saveAndFlush(animal);
    }

    public <T extends Animal> T save(final T animal) {
        return animalRepository.save(animal);
    }

    public List<Dog> findDogs() {
        return filterByType(animalRepository.findAll(), Dog.class);
    }

    private <T extends Animal> List<T> filterByType(final List<Animal> animals, final Class<T> type) {
        return animals
                .stream()
                .filter(type::isInstance)
                .map(account -> (T) account)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }


}
```

5. Finally my test

```
@SpringBootTest
class AnimalServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    AnimalService animalService;

    @Test
    void test() {
        Dog dog = animalService.saveAndFlush(new Dog());
        assertEquals(dog.getVersion(), 0L);

        var myDog = animalService.findDogs().get(0);
        myDog.setName("another name");

        myDog = animalService.saveAndFlush(myDog);
        assertEquals(myDog.getVersion(), 1L);
    }
}
```

If you try to run this code, it will fail with the following stacktrace:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
> not execute statement [ERROR: relation "animal" does not exist
> Position : 8] [update animal set version=? where id=? and version=?];
> SQL [update animal set version=? where id=? and version=?]

Hibernate(?) is trying to update the version of my dog but use animal as table name instead of dog...